# can't update the item of the dynamoDB table that has only partition key

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

The goal is to update one of the attributes in the DynamoDB table. Here is the schema:

```
{
  'job_id': {S: jobInfo.job_id} (partition_key),
  'company': {S: jobInfo.company},
  'title': {S: jobInfo.title},
  'posted_on': {S: jobInfo.posted_on},
  'clicks': {N: jobInfo.clicks}

}
```

The **primary key** of this table is only **partition_key** and it is **job_id**. Now I want to increment the **clicks** value and here is my **update param**:

```
  let params = {
    TableName: 'jobPosts',
    Key: {
        "job_id": "57a08a5c-ca6c-4056-b892-dc9e6388adb9"
    },
    UpdateExpression: "add clicks :value",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":value": {N: "1"}
    },
    ReturnValues:"ALL_NEW"
  };

  ddb.updateItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("In DynamoDB error");
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    } else {
      console.log("In DynamoDB Success");
      console.log(`Here is the data: ${data}`);
    }
  });
};
```

But, I get the **ValidationException** error with the message **The provided key element does not match the schema**. Here is the full stack trace:

```
{
    "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
    "code": "ValidationException",
    "time": "2019-11-17T04:23:11.495Z",
    "requestId": "4327RBE0UEHSND9Q4M7K44AEEFVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 37.586092348332265
}
```

The table **doesn't have a composite primary key**. It is just partition_key. I don't understand the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the key, use a format such as this:

```
Key={"job_id": {"S": "57a08a5c-ca6c-4056-b892-dc9e6388adb9"}}
```

It is confusing, but when specifying the key you must specify not only the field that is the key but the type of the key.  So in this case it is like the "value" for the job_id is a type/value pair, where "S" indicates this is a string type with "57a08a5c-ca6c-4056-b892-dc9e6388adb9" as the value of that string.  This shows the format for different types: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html